# Change Color of a public GameObject in script [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, gameobject

I created a gameobject call archor, it has a script attached to it, that script refers to a gameobject (e.g. Wall) through

`public GameObject Wall`  (in code)

Then I drag a prefab from Unity Editor into that slot

Now, inside the script, I would like to change Wall 's color through code

I have tried

```
Wall.SpriteRenderer.color = Color.Red;
Wall.material.color = Color.Red;
Wall.material.SetColor 
or even 
Wall.SpriteRenderer.SetColor
```

and none of them worked

Do I have to name the Renderer of Gameobject before I can refer to it ?

So if I have Wall , TallWall, ShortWall and I want to change their color, will I have to name each Renderer first?

What is the different between `Setcolor` and  `.color`?

All this code is put in `void Start()`

Thanks in advance quite confusing

I expect some simple explanation

Comment: I read a few more page, the Wall Gameobject did have a Sprite Renderer and it is active

Comment: do you have a 2d or 3d game? i think SpriteRenderer is only for 2d projects.

Comment: @Molbac you can use `SpriteRenderer` in 3d game if you want.

Comment: @AliakseiKalosha even for a 3d wall object like its described in the question?

Comment: @Molbac Yes if you want it to look like a made out of paper or it just visible from one side, yes nothing stop you from doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always should select right type of an object to use. You should change the variables type to the `SpriteRenderer` if it is a SpriteRenderer and you want to change it color. If it is a 3D model use `Renderer` instead.

`SetColor` allow you to set different color parameters in material, `color` will set just one of them.

So ith you are useing the sprite rendere your code could llok like this :

```
    public class WallColorChanger : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer wall;
        [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer wallTall;
        [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer wallShort;

        private void Start()
        {
            SetColor(wall, Color.white);
            SetColor(wallShort, Color.red);
            SetColor(wallTall, Color.white);
        }

        private void SetColor(SpriteRenderer sprite, Color color)
        {
            sprite.color = color;
        }
    }
```

If you case of them being a 3D objects you will need to change SetColor to work with Renderer and adjust the material value.

Comment: Sorry can you explain a bit further on the "select right type of an object " part?
The Wall is a prefab with only 3 component 
Transform
SpriteRenderer
and 
Sprites-Default

Thanks for your help

Comment: In your case you should use the `SpriteRenderer` because it is a `SpriteRenderer`.

So just to be clear `Transform` and `SpriteRenderer` are components. Sprite-Default it is a material used in `SpriteRenderer` to render the sprite. 

If you still have questions feel free to ask.
Next time please add screenshot of object as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great!
Just a quick question, if i am to said create buildings of different colors base on the same prefabs, what will be the better way to do it or simple change specific color before spawn, spawn with that color then the color stay with the prefabs until next time it spawn something else with another specific color?

Comment: i figure it out , you can always set it to color white to return it to default, plz ignore my last comment , thanks again